# Too few arguments given for UndirectedEdge

Tags: functions, function-construction, warning-messages

I want to sort this UndirectedEdge and got this warning.
The function still works and return correct result though. How can I fix this?

```
UndirectedEdge[Sequence @@ Sort[List @@ (b \[UndirectedEdge] a)]]
```

Warning: Too few arguments given for UndirectedEdge.

I don't want to do it in two steps.

Comment: But it works. right? On V13.0.1 you only see the front end complaining asking for second argument. I do not get any warning on console. But the call does what it is supposed to do. If you do not like to see the front end red ^ marker, you can do  `UndirectedEdge[Sequence @@ Sort[List @@ (b \[UndirectedEdge] a)], ""]`  ?   screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJXjP.png)

Comment: `Sort[b \[UndirectedEdge] a]`

Comment: Well, I tried Sort only and somehow I thought it didn't work!
Thanks.
Nasser tip adding "" is good too. I saw that error several times but didn't know how to fix it.